# Office 2013 appears twice in the taskbar

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, microsoft-outlook-2013

For some reason, Outlook 2013 now appears twice in the taskbar. It shows up with two different icons, the usual blue "o" and a yellow+folder icon:

[image]

It was just fine until now and it suddenly started for no obvious reason. When I close one of them, the other remains and I have to close it too to shut down Outlook completely. When opening it again, it opens the "correct" one (the blue O), waits a second or two and then opens the second one. Both apps look identical.

What's going on there?

Comment: Strange. What shows up when you open Task Manager?